# ASP.NET Core send data from table to modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-table, bootstrap-modal

In my application I have a table where you can delete a row.
When the user clicks on the delete icon, a modal pops up with the question if he really wants to delete the row.
On the button to confirm the modal I want to call a action method and pass the value of the row with it.
But how do I reach the value from the row from within the modal?

Here is my code:

```
@*Account table*@
<table id="account_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach (DataTable dt in Model.Tables)
{
    if (dt.TableName.Equals("account"))
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@dr[0]</td>
                <td>@dr[1]</td>
                <td>@dr[2]</td>
                <td>@dr[3]</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationAccountModal"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
}
```

```
@*Confirmation Account Modal*@
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmationAccountModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-danger">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="float: left;">DELETING ACCOUNT</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right;">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to delete this account?
            <hr />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            @Html.ActionLink("DELETE", "DeleteAccountAsync", "Admin", new { accountId = dr[0] }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", style = "float: right; width: auto; margin-right: 5px;" })
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

dr[0] isn't a valid value in my actionlink inside my modal.

Comment: You have to use jQuery to bind the value dynamically  to the modal.

Comment: Or, you know, just plain JavaScript; no need for jQuery :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value that should be passed to the controller action is dynamic, its best to call this action from JavaScript and that can be made easier using jQuery.

**HTML table:**

```html
<tr>
  <td>@dr[0]</td>
  <td>@dr[1]</td>
  <td>@dr[2]</td>
  <td>@dr[3]</td>
  <td class="text-center">
    <span id="delete-account-btn" account-id="@dr[what_ever_is_the_id]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmationAccountModal"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**modal:**

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Are you sure you want to delete this account?</p>
  <hr />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button id="btn-yes" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style = "float: right; width: auto; margin-right: 5px;">Yes</button>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var delAccountId;

$(document).delegate('#delete-account-btn',
'click',
function (e) {
  delAccountId = $(this).attr('account-id');
});

$(document).delegate('#btn-yes',
'click',
function (e) {
    var data = {
      accountId : delAccountId
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (returnvalue) {
           //what you want on success
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //what you want on error
        }
    });
});
```

So by clicking the icon in the row of the to be deleted account, you first store its model id in a JavaScript variable. Then by clicking the yes button inside the modal the controller action gets called with the id of the account to be deleted.